# maven not able to download mysql connector 8.0.12 from central

Tags: java, mysql, maven, download, connector

Maven is not able to download mysql connector 8.0.12 from central, showing the below error:

---

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector- 
java/8.0.12/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.pom
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.642 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-21T00:22:03+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/113M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project OneSolution: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project OneSolution:OneSolution:jar:1.1.1: Failed to 
collect dependencies at mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.12: Failed to 
read artifact descriptor for mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.12: Could 
not transfer artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:pom:8.0.12 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: 
protocol_version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

---

any help is appreciated, not getting enough suggestion online, trying here.

Comment: The message you posted has two suggestions already.

Comment: The first thing is this: `Received fatal alert: protocol_version` which implies you are using JDK 7 and you should read this: https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/

Comment: Thanks..@khmarbaise I have changed to JDK-1.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Solution 1:` Try `mvn clean install` in console.

`Solution 2:` It might happen because of the firewall on your computer. Turn off the firewall and try it again.

`Solution 3:` Check if your `pom.xml` has similar dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using intelliJ idea there is also an other option:

In the Maven tool window, click The Toggle Offline Mode button.

This will append the --offline option to all Maven commands that IntelliJ IDEA runs. It will also report any items that cannot be found in the local repository.

Or in Maven settings.xml:

```
<offline>false</offline>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this way in maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.12</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please improve this answer by adding some context. How does this dependency differ from the one in the accepted answer? What version is it?

Comment: The artifact has moved the question has mysql:mysql-connector-java. This answer is the new naming / repo com.mysql:mysql-connector-j